# No Reviews Tab Custom WooCommerce Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on a custom WooCommerce from a WordPress theme I have built from scratch. So far everything is working perfectly but I have come across an issue that I can't seem to get my head around. When I click on a product I am taken to the single product page, everything works as expected when I scroll down to the tabs section I am seeing the Description tab, but there is no reviews tab. I spent a big chunk of the weekend trying to find a solution to displaying this but I have been unsuccessful.

I have searched the project for the following lines to make sure I haven't disabled the functionality.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tab_panels', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_panel', 30);
```

I am completely stumped now. I have tried Google to find a solution, but I can only find articles and forum posts for pre-existing bought themes. Now I'm left wondering if I have actually missed something. I can display the review stars and it is correctly displaying the number of reviews but when I click on the url to go to the reviews the address bar displays `wp-lds-shop/product/happy-ninja/#reviews`.

I would really appreciate any help or advice on this.

Comment: Have you customized the WooCommerce templates in any way that may have affected the tabs?

Comment: Hey Michael, no I haven’t touched any of the templates. I might try a fresh Woocommerce install to see if this remedies the issue

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following solution, which worked for me.
You have to declare WooCommerce support, otherwise the "Review" tab will not show up.

I followed this link: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes and added this code at the bottom of my functions.php

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just saved my night.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Not sure why this is not enabled by default by Woocommerce and needed by custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This:
Reviews are enabled in:

[How to enable reviews remove Reviews tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvGhM.gif)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help! I have enabled Reviews in each of the products and I am still unable to see the reviews tab :(

Comment: If you are using a comment-disabling plugin or have comments off in your WordPress Discussion settings, Reviews will not display.

Enable reviews in the Product post by checking the Allow Reviews checkbox  at the bottom of the page.

If you don’t see this box, click Screen Options at the top-right and ensure Reviews and Product Reviews are both checked.

Answer (score 0):

**just add to function.php template**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'yikes_remove_description_tab', 20, 1 );

    function yikes_remove_description_tab( $tabs ) {

        // Remove the description tab
        if ( isset( $tabs['description'] ) ) unset( $tabs['description'] );             
        return $tabs;
    }
```